# Python: Protocol metaclass with read-only properties

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I want to achieve a Protocol with read-only properties with reduced boilerplate. In short:

```
# I want to reduce boilerplate of the following.
class MyVerboseProtocol(Protocol)
    @property
    def x(self):
        return x


# I want this to be functionally equivalent to MyVerboseProtocol
class MyProtocol(Protocol)
     x # this should be read-only


class MyClass(MyProtocol)
    x = 5


my_class = MyClass()
print(my_class.x) # should print 5
myclass.x = 4 # should raise some exception
```

I tried a metaclass but something with Protocol makes the property not read-only:

```
class MyMetaProtocol(type(Protocol) # needs type(Protocol) or something won't resolve
    @property
    def x(self): # pylance seems to want self here
        return self.x


class MyProtocol(Protocol, metaclass=MyMetaProtocol)
    x


class MyClass(MyProtocol)
    x = 5


my_class = MyClass()
print(my_class.x) # should print 5
myclass.x = 4 # seems fine??
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go with "simple is better". Violating the intuition behind Protocols is probably not worth a couple keystrokes of savings.

The other option was class decorators, but if we have the ability to modify the class in the first place it doesn't seem like it makes a lot of sense.